# Rest API - $filter multiple values

Tags: rest, filter, multiple-values

Assuming there is a list of Students each with a zip-code, how can I get records for multiple (but not all) zip-codes.

When using `$filter` how do specify multiple values?

Here's what I have so far:

`site.com/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Students')/items?$filter=ZipCode eq 12345`

When I try:

`site.com/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Students')/items?$filter=ZipCode eq '12345'&$filter=ZipCode eq '22222'`

Or

`site.com/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Students')/items?$filter=ZipCode eq '12345,22222'`

These don't work, what is the right way of doing this?

Comment: Please help us know the filter condition 'like'. Requires to extract the records related to city name starts with 'NEW%'

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As far as I know, you can not use `&`. You have to use `and` or `or` inside the `filter`.

So try using something like that:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Students')/items?$select=Title,ZIP&$filter=((ZIP eq 12345) or (ZIP eq 22222))
```

I always use brackets because of the readability, but you can also use it without brackets.

```
items?$select=Title,ZIP&$filter=ZIP eq 12345 or ZIP eq 22222
```

Comment: remove the parenthesis. `$filter=ZIP eq 12345 or ZIP eq 22222`

Comment: just a note. If the right Operand is a string then do include single quotes like this: /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Students')/items?$select=Title,ZIP&$filter=((ZIP eq 12345) or (CITY eq 'New York'))