# Rest query, get values IN a collection

Tags: list, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, caml-query, filter

I would like to get the items whose field A is IN (X,Y,Z...).

I've seen ways to do it with ORs ([Rest API - $filter multiple values](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163307/rest-api-filter-multiple-values)) but is there a simpler way?

Something like:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Students')/items?$select=Title,ZIP&$filter=(ZIP IN [111,222,333,444])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try to use [GetItems](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208020/make-caml-query-with-in-rest-api-call) endpoint in REST APIs where you can use [IN operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/in-element-query)(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/in-element-query) in CAML query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **IN operator** in CAML query with SharePoint REST API's **GetItems** endpoint.

Example of IN operator uses:

```
<Where>
  <In>
    <FieldRef Name="ID" />
    <Values>
       <Value Type="Number">1</Value>
       <Value Type="Number">2</Value>
       .
       .
       .
       <Value Type="Number">530</Value>
    </Values>
  </In>
</Where>
```

**References**:

1. [In element (Query)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/in-element-query)
2. [Make CAML query with in rest api call](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208020/make-caml-query-with-in-rest-api-call)
3. [SharePoint REST API - CAML Query](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-rest-api-caml-query)

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to use it in the filters in the url of the REST query? If so, what's the syntax? I've googled around but no luck.

Comment: You need to write CAML query for filters check 2 reference link. it has the example given for the same